# How can I add a (vertical) margin (i.e., padding) between page header and content on the second page with repeating table header in Telerik reporting

Tags: text-formatting, margins

I am using Telerik Report Designer Software.

I have a problem: I want to set a margin between the page header
and the table header when the table header is repeating.

On the first page it looks good, but on the second page it looks like this:
[image: Second Page of Telerik Report]
(where the red represents the page header
and the grey represents the table header.)

How can I put space/margin/line break between page header and table header on the second page of the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be to add a parent group header section in-between the page header section and the table (the table's parent section). Then set PrintOnEveryPage = True for this group header section.

For more Information you can visit this [link](https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-can-i-add-a-(vertical)-margin-(i-e-padding)-between-page-header-and-content-on-the-second-page-with-repeating-table-header-in-telerik-reporting)